# Porting a java game to android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

I have a basic noob question which I'm sure many of you can easily answer.

I am finishing up a game I am making in java.   It is a windowed game, and I am not using any flow layouts.  In other words, I am placing the images and buttons myself using setbounds, etc.  I want to port this game to android, where it will be full screen.

I have heard that I should use Eclipse or libgdx to do this. My question is, will my game still retain its dimensions on an android phone?  Will it scale to a viewable size
or will I have to adjust everything on my game to make it fit?

I'm also wondering how difficult is it to port it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will my game still retain its dimensions on an android phone? Will it scale to a viewable size? Or will I have to adjust everything on my game to make it fit?

Yes. If you use a camera in libgdx (which you should!). It will scale everything to fit the screen, stretching it. But you can easily set it to keep aspect ratio and show black bars at the sides. [For example this](http://www.acamara.es/blog/2012/02/keep-screen-aspect-ratio-with-different-resolutions-using-libgdx/).

> I'm wondering how difficult is it to port it.

The library is very easy to use, it depends on your current game design/implementation. But yeah, it must be very easy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using libgdx at the moment it will be hard to port it to libgdx. May be a big part of your game has to be rewritten. But if you are allready using libgdx for the desktop version of your game you only have to handle the different input type (most times on android phones you use touch input instead of keyboard). If you are using libgdx but you are not using camera, you should definitly modify your game to use camera. By doing this you do not depend on screen aspect ration ([One possible solution](http://www.acamara.es/blog/2012/02/keep-screen-aspect-ratio-with-different-resolutions-using-libgdx/)). Also you should then keep in mind, that on android the method `pause()` is called when call is incoming or homebutton is pressed and `resume()` is called when user returns to game. Hope this helps.

Comment: I planned on making my game portable to android or iOS from the start so everything is buttonbased depending on mouse clicks. Its a turned based rpg basically. I heard android converts button/mouse clicks to touch anyways. Will this make it easier for me to port to libgdx? Any help is appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: Well it depends on the design of your game. Try reading some tutorials about libgdx to have an idea of it and the you will see what you have to change/what will be the same.

Comment: @CameronRoberson did you allready port your game? Or do you have any problems with it? If any of the answers helped you please accept it. If you stil have a problem with this update your question. Thanks

Comment: havent ported the game yet. I still have more questions and its not quite finished yet. Im hoping all i will have to do is setup a camera. Thanks,

Comment: @CameronRoberson well if you separated the logic and the view/render logic you can definitly use your logic. But the view and some other things like screen management and starting/closing/stoping the game you will have to redo. But i think this could be done pretty fast.